# Setting the location property of PHAssetChangeRequest doesn't create a GPS section in image metatdata

Tags: ios, objective-c, gps, photokit

When a picture is taken (iOS 8.1) and didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo is called, I'm trying to use PhotoKit to add the GPS data back into the metadata.

This is the code I'm using:

```
 UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
[[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] performChanges:^{

    PHAssetChangeRequest *newAssetRequest = [PHAssetChangeRequest creationRequestForAssetFromImage:image];
    newAssetRequest.creationDate = [NSDate date];
    newAssetRequest.location = [self deviceLocation];
    NSLog(@"didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: location:%@",  newAssetRequest.location);

    PHObjectPlaceholder *placeholderAsset = newAssetRequest.placeholderForCreatedAsset;

    PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest *addAssetRequest = [PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest changeRequestForAssetCollection:self.myResults[0]];
    [addAssetRequest addAssets:@[placeholderAsset]];

} completionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
    if (success) {
        NSLog(@"didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: Success saving picture to album");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: error saving picture to album %@", error);
    }
}];

[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

The code takes the image and moves it to an album. This part works. The photo ends up in the correct album.

The problem is the GPS data is not present in the metadata even though the location property is properly set. I know the location data is valid.

Shouldn't this work? Is there an alternate approach to get the desired result? I don't really care about all the other metadata, just the GPS coordinates.

Comment: Did you figure a way to do this?

Comment: Never did. My understanding is this information is stripped at every opportunity for security reasons. I ended up keeping lat lon in my meta data store. My dream of keeping each image as a database died.

Comment: I'm using more or less the same code to save an image.  Within the iOS Photos app it places the image on the map in the correct location. When I import the photo to my mac with Image Capture it shows in the preview the correct GPS coordinates. However, once it's imported I don't see any location information in the EXIF of the image... strange.